# selecting 2 different option values and sending data to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am taking two different values from `select` options and sending it using AJAX, but PHP is not responding to the request.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#updateStatus").change(function() {
    var opt = $("#updateStatus").val();

    $("#updateStatus1").change(function() {
      var sta = $("#updateStatus1").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'updatecode.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "option=" + opt + "&status=" + sta,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data + "hello");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$id = $_POST['opt'];
$status = $_POST['sta'];
$query = "UPDATE projectstable SET projectStatus='".$status."'WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (!$row) {
  echo json_encode("fail");
} else {
  echo json_encode("sucess");
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: have you tried `console.log(opt)` and `console.log(sta)`.

Comment: Nope ill try it and see.

Comment: console isn't showing any errors ajax sending data to php but its not recieving any

Comment: you need to change this   $id = $_POST['option'];
$status = $_POST['status'];  check my answer below..

Comment: i think ajax is not invoking my PHP file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your existing ajax function like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var opt = '';
  var sta = '';
  $("#updateStatus").change(function() {
     opt = $("#updateStatus").val();
  });

  $("#updateStatus1").change(function() {
     sta = $("#updateStatus1").val();
     callAjax(opt,sta);
  });
});

function callAjax(opt,sta) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'updatecode.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "opt=" + opt + "&sta=" + sta,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data + "hello");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It worked but had to change the " data:{opt:opt,sta:sta}"

Comment: @Parvez Now check my answer i just edit it. And please accept it, if it is helpful to you.. it will helps me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#updateStatus,#updateStatus1").change(function () {

                    var opt = $("#updateStatus").val();
                    var sta = $("#updateStatus1").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'updatecode.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {option:opt,status:sta},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data + "hello");
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
```

and php code should like this

```
$id = $_POST['option'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$query = "UPDATE projectstable SET projectStatus='".$status."'WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (!$row) {
   echo json_encode("fail");
 } else {
 echo json_encode("sucess");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the json body as a query string, and you are declaring to use `dataType: "json"`

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'updatecode.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "option=" + opt + "&status=" + sta,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data + "hello");
        }
 });
```

instead that you should do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'updatecode.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"option": opt, "status": sta},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data + "hello");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request under *data* using "option=" and "&status=" but you are reading these values in PHP through $_POST['opt'] and $_POST['stat'] which should actually be $_POST['**option**'] and $_POST['**status**'] respectively.
Also you need to change the data request to JSON format like data: {option:opt,status:sta} for your dataType is JSON

Comment: Try getting the error by adding error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.log(errorThrown);
    }  in ajax request after success function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one looks like i just had to change some code in ajax this is my new code which is working fine
This is my PHP code I got rid of if(!$row)

```
                mysql_select_db("dts_db",$con);
            $id=$_POST['opt'];

            $status=$_POST['sta'];

            $query="UPDATE projectstable SET projectStatus='".$status."'WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);if(!$result){    die("My sql query result ".mysql_error());}
```

else {

echo json_encode("success");

}
and this is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: 'updatecode.php',
type: 'POST',
data:  {opt:opt,sta:sta},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
  alert(data + "hello");
}
```

});